# How can I have a mixin with multiple selectors?

Tags: css, less, mixins, less-mixins

The following code:

```
.positionBase (@name,@size: 16px,@position: 0) {
    [disabled] .icon.@{name}, .disabled .icon.@{name}, .disabled.icon.@{name} {
        background-position: @position*@size -@size;
    }

    .icon.@{name} {
        background-position: @position*@size 0;
    }

    .icon.@{name}.dark {
        background-position: @position*@size -2*@size;
    }

    .icon.@{name}.dark:hover, a:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, button:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, .button:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, .interactable:hover .icon.@{name}.dark {
        background-position: @position*@size -3*@size;
    }
}

* {
    .positionBase(testing,16px,0)
}
```

produces as I would expect:

```
* [disabled] .icon.testing,
* .disabled .icon.testing,
* .disabled.icon.testing {
  background-position: 0px -16px;
}
* .icon.testing {
  background-position: 0px 0;
}
* .icon.testing.dark {
  background-position: 0px -32px;
}
* .icon.testing.dark:hover,
* a:hover .icon.testing.dark,
* button:hover .icon.testing.dark,
* .button:hover .icon.testing.dark,
* .interactable:hover .icon.testing.dark {
  background-position: 0px -48px;
}
```

How do I get rid of the `*` prefix and just have the selectors without the prefix?

Things that don't work:

`.positionBase(testing,16px,0)`

```
* {
    .positionBase(testing,16px,0)
}
```

and

```
{
    .positionBase(testing,16px,0)
}
```

My Google foo is weak, I've found nothing that would make me think this is possible, in which case I want to use the `*` prefix, but that is also very bad for performance. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `.positionBase(testing,16px,0);` should work (make sure you include a semi-colon at the end! That can cause less compilation to fail if left out)

I tested it out here: http://lesstester.com/ and it worked just fine.

```
.positionBase (@name,@size: 16px,@position: 0) {
    [disabled] .icon.@{name}, .disabled .icon.@{name}, .disabled.icon.@{name} {
        background-position: @position*@size -@size;
    }

    .icon.@{name} {
        background-position: @position*@size 0;
    }

    .icon.@{name}.dark {
        background-position: @position*@size -2*@size;
    }

    .icon.@{name}.dark:hover, a:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, button:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, .button:hover .icon.@{name}.dark, .interactable:hover .icon.@{name}.dark {
        background-position: @position*@size -3*@size;
    }
}

.positionBase(testing,16px,0);
```

Comment: so apparently you don't need the semi-color after EVERY line, just lines that are in the middle of a bracket set, or stand-alone lines.... moral: always use semi-colons.